# Error when trying to consume SOAP PROJUDI-PR

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl, wsimport

Good afternoon !

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service from PROJUDI-PR but I'm having problems converting the xml into java.

> https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/webservices/projudiIntercomunicacaoWebService222?wsdl

To convert the xml into java I used windows powershell.

command used:

```
wsimport -keep https://projudi.tjpr.jus.br/projudi/webservices/projudiIntercomunicacaoWebService222?wsdl
```

expected the shell to do the conversion correctly so that it could then consume its methods.

[image]

Comment: PowerShell is incidental to your problem, so I removed the tag. The problem is that  `wsimport` thinks the referenced WSDL is invalid.

Comment: And how can I convert to java using other tools

Comment: That's the problem so far I haven't written any code I'm just trying to convert it to java to later have access to the methods. The only code I've written so far is PowerShell, wsimport -keep, and the xml I'm converting.

Comment: You need to investigate why `wsimport` considers the WSDL invalid. Perhaps it is, perhaps it isn't and you need additional `wsimport` options to make it work - I personally don't know. PowerShell has no built-in WSDL-related functionality. Your question's tags will hopefully attract subject-matter experts.